# Sagemaker xgboost regression with multi-dimansional targets

Tags: amazon-web-services, regression, xgboost, amazon-sagemaker

I'm using XGBoost Regression from Amazon Sagemaker and I have a dataset with categorical features where I want to have a multi-dimensional target. Is this at all possible with their APIs?

The features would be integers starting from 0 and the target would have to be a vector consisting of 2 float numbers ranging from -100 to 100 (e.g `[21.57, -64.90]`).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the XGBoost Regressor algorithm expects a single value for the target variable. I'd recommend using the XGBoost container in Script Mode and providing your own training script that uses the target variables you want.